# Oracle sys SYSDBA audit information to a report

Tags: oracle, audit

I am trying to produce a monthly report on Audit.

I am able to query the `DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL`, for all other users and no issue in that.

I wanted to include the `SYS`/`SYSDBA` activities in this report and I know this is not recorded in `SYS.AUD$` table but its recorded as an operating system files called `.AUD`. I know this is done to make sure that DBAs don't go and modify these data.

Because this is just a reporting how can I get this details to my report?

Is there a way I can query the operating system files eg. `XXXX.AUD` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you already know that SYS user audit information is stored in an OS file there is no such tables or views to query in the database.

Workaround is to create an external table.

Here is an example from AskTom.

[Audit file as External Table input](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:49816098271374)